# Unique data in Many to Many relations

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I use Doctrine2 as ORM in a Symfony2 project. I have `article` and `tag` entity classes. There are many-to-many relations between them. An article may have many tags and vice versa. There is a joined table, `article_tags` which just have 2 columns `article_id` and `tag_id`, and generated by doctrine. Everything works fine, except, when new article with some tags is added, both new and pre-existing tags are inserted into `tag` table in which **I want to only store unique tags**; the `article_tags` should just relate them.

My article schema:

```
  manyToMany:
    tags:
      targetEntity: Tag
      cascade: ["persist"]
      joinTable:
    name: article_tag
    joinColumns:
      article_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
    inverseJoinColumns:
      tag_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Adding unique attribute to `tag` and ignoring duplicates is not reasonable since there should be relation. I tried to add logic that checks if the tag exists fetch tag data and add it to article:

```
$article->addTag($existingTag);
```

It gives the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Seferov\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article::addTag() must be an instance of
>   Seferov\ArticleBundle\Entity\Tag, null given, called in
>   /var/www/seferov.local/src/Seferov/ArticleBundle/Repository/TagRepository.php
>   on line 34 and defined in
>   /var/www/seferov.local/src/Seferov/ArticleBundle/Entity/Article.php
>   line 393

Comment: So you passed a function expecting a specific object instance a null value...is that your question? Or are you asking how to have unique data?

Comment: I want to have unique data. The others are what I have tried. Any way to solve unique data problem is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to check if the tag exists.  If it does then use it.  If not then create one.

```
public function loadOrg($orgId,$autoCreate = false)
{
    $org = $this->getEntityManager()->find('ZaysoCoreBundle:Org',$orgId);
    if ($org) return $org;

    if (!$autoCreate) return null;
    if (!$orgId)      return null;

    $org = new Org();
    $org->setId($orgId);
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($org);
    return $org;
}
```

Be sure to make your tag column unique and to catch exceptions.  Possibility that another request might insert the same tag in between the find and the persist.